# i'm having trouble with adding new replies using laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Before question , This is my code

**Show.blade.php**

```html
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    @if ($comment->post_id == $post->id)
    .....
        <form action="{{ route('createreply', ['rid' => $comment->id]) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="replyContent" id="replyContent" style="color:white" />
            <button type=" submit" style=" color :lavender " class="btn btn-secondary">comment</button>
        </form>
    ....
    @endif
@endforeach
```

(( comment is original comment, and i made reply for answer of comment ))

**web.php  (route)**

```
Route::post('/replycreate', [CommentController::class, 'createReply'])->name('createreply');
```

**my controller (comment)**

```
public function createReply(Request $request, $rid)
{
    $reply = new Reply();

    $reply->replyContent = $request->replyContent;
    $reply->user_name = Auth::user()->name;
    $reply->comment_id = $rid;

    dd($reply);

    $reply->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I have problem with making re-reply,
and my code returns error  and it says

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::createReply(), 1 passed in C:\Users\ALSACE\post-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

I tought i had used two argument , but this kind of error occurs.

so i tought using `dd($reply)`,
`dd()` can't even complete.

you can guess `$rid` is empty ..  but in the same `Show.blade.php` , I had used `$comment` with no problem so i think i can not be problem.

plz help with newbe Laravel student!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createReply` method expect 2 arguments,  BUT you don't have variable in your route.
You must change the route to:

```
Route::post('/replycreate/{rid}', [CommentController::class, 'createReply'])->name('createreply');
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the id to the route itself. If you're going to require it in the function parameters, then it needs to be added on the route URL.

```
Route::post('/replycreate/{rid}', [CommentController::class, 'createReply'])->name('createreply');
```